# What is proper name for the WINAPI tag in a c function?

Tags: c, winapi, tags

I'm having a hard time understanding what the WINAPI tag is with respect to c.

For example:

BOOL WINAPI CreateProcessA( ...);

What exactly is this WINAPI tag, does it have more formal name, and is it part of c or implementation specific?

Sorry if my question is a bit confusing.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the standard's terms, it is a *storage class specifier* (like "static"), a *type specifier* (like "unsigned"), or a *type qualifier* (like "const").  The difference is very roughly that if it were either kind of specifier, you could not write

```
BOOL * WINAPI CreateProcessA(...);
```

but if it were a qualifier, you could.  Regardless, it is a nonstandard feature of compilers for Windows.

(I see that other people have pointed out that in fact "WINAPI" is a macro, but it's a macro provided by the implementation, so you're supposed to treat it as a language feature and not look at what it expands to.)

Comment: I think you mean "storage-class specifier" rather than "type specifier". "static" is a storage-class specifier. A "type-specifier" is something like "unsigned int".

Comment: @Laurence: I had forgotten that there were two kinds of specifier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It is a macro defining the [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58(v=VS.90).aspx), usually `#define WINAPI __stdcall` in Windows.

Comment: Which is a huge misnomer since "__stdcall" is completely **nonstandard** and contrary to normal C and normal x86 calling conventions and extremely inefficient.

Comment: In x86, the difference is \_\_stdcall functions return and clean up the stack in one assembly language instruction, whereas \_\_cdecl functions just return and the caller has to clean up the stack in a 2nd instruction.  How is that *extremely* inefficient?  It seems possibly *more* efficient.

Comment: @R.. That __stdcall is nonstandard is a non-sequitur. That it is not the normal way of doing things in C is also a non-sequitur. However, it is the standard calling convention on Windows x86 and so its name is quite reasonable.

Comment: My bad, I forgot x86 had the weird `ret` opcode that could perform adjustments to the stack pointer after popping the return address, and was assuming you'd have to go through the otherwise-hell of moving the return address to a new location on the stack to return and screwing up the cpu's lookahead/prediction.

Answer (score 1):

It's a macro, i.e. the preprocessor replaces it with whatever it is #defined to before the actual compilation. Specifically, the WINAPI macro is defined to tell which calling convention the function uses.

Answer (score -2):

```
#define WINAPI __stdcall
```

this means that arguments of `CreateProcessA` will be calculated starting from left to right.

Comment: incorrect, the arguments are still pushed on the stack right to left, but the function is required to clean up the stack instead of the caller.

Comment: @Mirhan AFAI remember it means some mix of C and Pascal calling convention - how the arguments are pushed to the stack, and who cleans the stack - caller or the function itself.

Comment: Calling conventions are documented [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Whether this is correct or not, I don't you've addressed what the question was asking.

Comment: There are no sequence points between function arguments.  The order in which arguments are calculated is completely undetermined, and the calling convention does not change this.